# What changes need to be made to a base ASP.NET (framework) application to move Identity from localdb to SQL azure?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

I need to know what changes I need to make to my web config to allow for the application to save and retrieve users from azure.

I've attempted to do this several times, and each time when i get this working user saves and reads default to localdb even though I have properly configured all connection strings sections. I believe this has something to do with the "defaultConnectionFactory".

Default web.config, please post a working one with redacted username/password:

```
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>

      <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-CLTech.Web-20170410052535.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-CLTech.Web-20170410052535;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: You need to provide the correct connection string to connect to your database. You can't use LocalDB in Azure.

Comment: You can find the Azure connection string with the steps mentioned in this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-dotnet

Comment: I can connect to azure sql with no problems. Identity is the issue, my user accounts keep getting stored in localdb.

Comment: Then you need to make sure Identity is receiving the correct connection string. It's as simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to update your Connection String to point to your SQL Azure Database instead of localdb. Be sure to migrate the database contents (schema and data) into the Azure SQL Database too.

ADO.NET is fully compatible with both SQL Server and Azure SQL Database. Not code changes are necessary.